# How do I make my application use the Windows theme?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, winapi, themes

I'm working with some windows API to create a little application.
I already created the buttons, windows, alright.

But the problem is the components I created don't look like the OS theme. They look very simple:

[image: As you can see on image]

See the button as example.

How do I enable the Windows theme? It can be in C or Delphi.

Comment: You need to specify how you create the application. Are you using the Delphi VCL? Are you creating a plain C application in Notepad?

Comment: I'm using Delphi IDE, just to compile, but I'm not using any file from it.
Here goes my source code, http://gist.github.com/615680.
Is 3 files, program, uAPI, uMain, simple like that.

Answer (score 6):

For an application using windows controls, that is documented in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Edit: To make a long story short, Windows needs to know for an application if it was intended to use the new style controls. Some older apps just aren't compatible with the new skinned looks of XP and later. Each exe should therefore declare with which version it is compatible in a manifest, an embedded xml file in the executable. The manifest is used for other things like declaring what you are or aren't compatible with (DLL versions, 120 dpi) as well as registration-free com.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make it on code.
I want the components as the theme of the SO, that is the same behavior the components have when created by Delphi IDE.

Comment: I'm no delphi expert. I googled an article about delph and manifests though: http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc111601a.htm

Comment: Only Microsoft would make it an "opt-in" feature to *fit in and use the standard look*

Answer (score 3):

1. It depends on what version of Delphi
   you're using. IIRC pre-Delphi 6 you
   need to add the needed manifest by
   hand. D7 and later has a component
   that need to be dropped on a form to
   add theme support (it simply adds the manifest), until D2007 IIRC
   added a simple check in the project
   options.
2. Earlier version of Delphi won't show themed design form. You will see themes only at run time.
3. Not all controls may support themes. Themes require the proper draw API to be called, if a control doesn't comply it won't be themed. The standard grid is a good example, it isn't draw themed until a late version.

Comment: Yes. I just want to make a remark on the third point. Most VCL controls, such as `TButton`, `TEdit`, `TListBox` etc. are simply wrappers for OS controls, and hence, the rendering is done by Windows, not by Delphi code. These are easily themed the normal way. Now, some VCL controls, such as `TGrid`, are not native OS controls, but rather drawn by Delphi code. These will look exactly as the developer made them look. It is possible to use Windows API or `ThemeServices` to query properties/draw details of the curnt. theme, though. So some such controls are "themed" in some sense while most aren't.

Comment: In D7, the component that has to be added is `TXPManifest`. It's on the `Win32` component panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Delphi 2007 or later, Project > Options > Application > Use Windows Themes needs to be checked.

(This should be automatically checked for new applications).

Comment: If you're using standard windows controls (which VCL is a wrapper around) it should work.

Comment: You can create a Windows control the Win API way, using CreateWindow etc. This is what `TButton`, `TEdit` etc. does. Most VCL controls are simply wrappers for standard Windows controls.

Comment: If you create all the vcl on runtime, this option isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

In [Visual Styles Reference: Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486120%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of MSDN, I found an interesting functions, that is, [SetWindowTheme()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). It can be used to either to apply or remove visual style to/from a control/window, there are [several steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#no_extensions) need to be done to enable Visual Style in an application.

To use Windows Theme api, you'll need `JwaUxTheme` unit of JEDI API Library.

However, applying theme from Windows Theme files (`.theme`) to an application seems has to be done by turning off visual style from controls and write owner drawn controls based on information from `.theme` files. MSDN has a documentation about `.theme` file specification (see the first reference below).

**Some good references:**

- [Creating and Installing Theme Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Fully themed Windows Vista Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/themedvistacontrols.aspx)
- [Creating Windows Vista Ready Applications with Delphi](http://www.installationexcellence.com/articles/VistaWithDelphi/Index.html)

Is Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Themes bad? There is a code example how to load it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfskins.aspx).

If you use VCL, [Theme Engine](http://www.ksdev.com/themeengine/) and [Skin Engine](http://www.ksdev.com/skinengine/) has a complete support of themes for Windows XP.

If beauty application is your priority (without supports for Windows themes), I think, [BusinessSkinForm](http://www.almdev.com/prods/bsf/bsf.htm) and [DynamicSkinForm](http://www.almdev.com/prods/dsf/dsf.htm) is the best choice.

Comment: I don't intend to use other skin, just use the Windows Standard, but when creating the components by VCL it isn't set by default.

Comment: So, you need a pure Windows API way to apply theme to your application. I have made a google search and found a light to start get into it. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your executable name is YourAppName.exe then, create a manifest file named YourAppName.exe.manifest in the same directory where the executable application is.

YourAppName.exe.manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
  manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    name="YourAppName"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    version="1.0.0.0"
    type="win32"/>
<description>MyApp</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

For embedding manifest file into executable use mt.exe 
commandline syntax:

```html
mt.exe –manifest YourAppName.exe.manifest -outputresource:YourAppName.exe;1
```