# Group Box look and feel

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition. I have designed the following dialog in the dialog editor-:
 [image: Dialog that I designed]

Please pay close attention to the group box in the dialog called 'Tasks'. It looks fine over here but when I display it as a modeless dialog box from my application the look and feel of that GroupBox suddenly changes to -:
[image: Dialog box when displayed from application]

Suddenly the original blue caption and rounded edges specified in the dialog editor are gone and are replaced with a black foreground and square edges. **I want to know why this is suddenly happening and I want it to be displayed with the look and feel specified in the dialog editor.**

The following code is present in my resource file(Timer.rc) for the dialog-:

```
IDD_FORMVIEW DIALOGEX 0, 0, 204, 118
STYLE DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SETFONT | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_CENTER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
CAPTION "SR-Timer(Work in Progress)"
FONT 10, "Verdana", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "Shutdown",IDC_RADIO1,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,73,37,48,10
    CONTROL         "Restart",IDC_RADIO2,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,73,54,39,10
    CONTROL         "Stand By",IDC_RADIO3,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,73,70,44,10
    CONTROL         "Hibernate",IDC_RADIO4,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,73,87,47,10
    GROUPBOX        "Tasks",IDC_STATIC,59,28,90,78
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual styles are also absent from the radio buttons as you can easily see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my application use the Windows theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884525/how-do-i-make-my-application-use-the-windows-theme)

Answer (score 4):

You should enable the XP common control style.

The easiest way to do this is to include this in your manifest file, e.g. by adding it to the linker, or adding a pragma in your code, like this:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

**EDIT:** It might also be needed to explicitly initialize the common controls (not 100% sure), like this:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX    InitStr;
InitStr.dwSize = sizeof(InitStr);
InitStr.dwICC  = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES|ICC_DATE_CLASSES|ICC_COOL_CLASSES;
// Other classes are: ICC_COOL_CLASSES, ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES, ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS, ICC_USEREX_CLASSES
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitStr);
```

It might also be needed to compile with the correct windows version defines.  I compile using these command line options:

```
/D_WIN32_WINNT#0x0501 /DWINVER#0x0501 /D_WIN32_IE#0x0500
```

But this always implies that the application needs at minimum Windows XP.

**EDIT2 (as an answer to sreyan's comment):**

I tried compiling the following source file (called test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") 

void main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Using the following commands:

```
cl /EHsc /MD /c test.cpp
link test.obj
```

And the following files were generated:

```
23-04-12  10:49             9 728 test.exe
23-04-12  10:49               638 test.exe.manifest
23-04-12  10:49            16 812 test.obj
```

The test.exe.manifest file contains this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

So this seems to be working correctly.

Recheck the options you filled in in Visual Studio, and the pragma you've added.
Try with a small app first (like the one above) until you get it working correctly.
Then move on to your big application.  If it doesn't work, compare what's different with the small app.

Success.

Comment: This does not work. I have pasted the code in the following way-:

#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND , UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CALLBACK DialogFunc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

char szWinName[]="Timer Main Window";

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
       LPSTR lpszArgs, int nWinMode)...
Am i missing something???

Comment: Thank You for the info, but I need my application to be running from Win 2000 and up. By the way what is the meaning of the #pragma comment and the command line option that you have givengiven I can't make sense of it, no offense I am just new to the Win32 API and want to know.

Comment: The pragma tells the compiler to add text (for the linker) somewhere in the generated .OBJ file.  The linker will pick up this info from the .OBJ file and use the text as additional command line option (you can use this trick to add any option to the linker).  The /manifestdependency option tells the linker to add this dependency to the generated manifest file (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0y5khy(v=vs.80).aspx).  Finally, you can use the manifest tool to indluce the manifest as a resource in the executable (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx).

Comment: Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx contains a good explanation about this.

Comment: /manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

I have added the above line to the additional manifest dependencies section in the linker area from the properties page.

But I am getting the error that manifest file could not be generated.

\Debug\Timer.exe.intermediate.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest.

I know I am missing something is there an entire project that I could refer to ??

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this requires a manifest and/or a call to `InitCommonControls()`. See [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @ Joey Excuse me I am using Windows XP Professional so should'nt these styles be activated by default. I mean why go to all this trouble just to activate the look and feel of the current OS ????

Comment: @ Joey I added the following line at the top of the code-:
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

And then included CommCtrl.h to my programme but I got the following error-:

Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__InitCommonControls@0 referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>C:\Documents and Settings\Sreyan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Timer\Debug\Timer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Sreyan, the themed controls are different from the normal ones which is why you need to link against a different version of the common controls.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial on the net regarding this topic because the msdn explanation isn't exactly beginner friendly.